# How to stop Eclipse from inserting blank line between import groups in Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I'm using this version of Eclipse:
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200

I think I've set every possible setting Eclipse has to disable blank lines between all imports, but it still automatically inserts one between import groups anytime a new import is automatically added by the program.

An example of what I'm talking about:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

I've set multiple settings that would seem to affect this, the main one that seems like it should absolutely control it is
Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter->Active Profile->Edit->Blank Lines->Blank lines within compilation unit
I have all settings there set to 0.
This includes "Between import groups", which I assume is intended to control exactly what I'm asking about.
However it doesn't work.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the ***Remove excess blank lines*** button right of the *Between import groups* selector **is pressed**.

Comment: That button doesn't exist in my version of Eclipse.

Comment: @Brent212 Yeah, you missed some time to update. Now you are three releases behind. Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades) asap.